# Align divs side by side in table data - CSS

Tags: html, css

I want to display divs side by side in a responsive table.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div>
   <table>
      <tr>
         <td class="td-prio" style="width: 100px; height: 100px;">
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="E3kRzMgJDPbcBeWwY" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  Test1
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  Test 1 Body
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="ASDdsgADogiesbfd" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  Test2
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  Test 2 Body
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default" id="ifsdfuHKJFSas4t" style="border-style: solid; cursor: move;">
               <div class="panel-heading">
                  Test3
               </div>
               <div class="panel-body">
                  Test 3 Body
               </div>
            </div>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </table>
</div>
```

At the moment it looks like this:

[image: Tbl_1]

And here is the desired result:

[image: Tbl_2]

Or if the table width is smaller:

[image: Tbl_3]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write this into your css:

```
.panel{
    float: left;
}
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1rzo0rtw/).

(Note that I needed to change the td's width too `500px`, in order to make space for multiple div's.)

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't set width to your `.td-prio` if you wants to get responsive effect.
In addition you can add

```
float: left
```

to your divs

Here is jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yLL7erv/